# Charts on the complex submanifold $E=\{(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n: z_1^2+z_2^2+\cdots+z_n^2=1\} $

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

It is known that the complex sphere

$$E=\{(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n: z_1^2+z_2^2+\cdots+z_n^2=1\} $$

is a complex unbounded submanifold in $\mathbb{C}^n$. See for example Page 39 of [Paul M. Gauthier's lecture notes for MAT6140 course](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Egauthier/6140.pdf).

Now I need to know the expression of charts on $E$, for any

$$a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in E$$

with some $a_{j}\neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we assume $a_1\neq 0$, define (a projection map)

$$ \eta_a(z)=  (z_2-a_2,z_3-a_3,\cdots,z_n-a_n)$$

for $z$ in some neighborhood of $a$, is it a chart? How to check that?

I think it is similar to the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$, we can take

$$ \varphi(x)=(x_1,x_2)$$

on $\{ (x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{S}^{2}:x_3>0\}$.

Comment: (holomorphic) implicit function theorem

Comment: Thanks! so is $\eta_a(z)$ a chart?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the implicit function theorem? What did you get?

Comment: I have checked that, then how about the coordinate changes if two charts overlap? (to get differential structures)

Comment: *What* have you checked?